# python3, directory is not correct when import a module in sub-folder

Tags: python-3.x, module, getcwd

I have a main folder called 'test', the inner structure is:

```
# folders and files in the main folder 'test'
Desktop\test\use_try.py
Desktop\test\cond\__init__.py   # empty file.
Desktop\test\cond\tryme.py
Desktop\test\db\
```

Now in the file tryme.py. I want to generate a file in the folder of 'db'

```
# content in the file of tryme.py
import os

def main():
    cwd = os.getcwd()    # the directory of the folder 'Desktop\test\cond'
    folder_test = cwd[:-4]   # -4 since 'cond' has 4 letters
    folder_db = folder_test + 'db/'  # the directory of folder 'db'

    with open(folder_db + 'db01.txt', 'w') as wfile:
        wfile.writelines(['This is a test.'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I directly run this file, no problem, the file 'db01.txt' is in the folder of 'db'.
But if I run the file of use_try.py, it will not work.

```
# content in the file of use_try.py
from cond import tryme

tryme.main()
```

The error I got refers to the tryme.py file. In the command of 'with open ...'

```
FileNotFoundError: [Error 2] No such file or directory: 'Desktop\db\db01.txt'
```

It seems like the code

```
'os.getcwd()'
```

only refers to the file that calls the tryme.py file, not the tryme.py file itself.

Do you know how to fix it, so that I can use the file use_try.py to generate the 'db01.txt' in the 'db' folder? I am using Python3

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like what you need is **not** the [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), but the directory of the `tryme.py` file.

This can be resolved using the `__file__` magic:

```
curdir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

Comment: Solves my problem completely. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute filenames from an environment variable, or expect the db/ directory to be a subdirectory of the current working directory.

This behavior is as expected.  The current working directory is where you invoke the code from, not where the code is stored.

```
folder_test = cwd   # assume working directory will have the db/ subdir
```

or
    folder_test = os.getEnv('TEST_DIR')  # use  ${TEST_DIR}/db/